# Filter dataframe by variable number

Tags: python, pandas, variables, filter

I want to filter the data by id_main_product and calculate the mean of the rating for each id. I know that I could do it the following way:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fredzett/Notebooks/master/01_case_sales_data.csv")
id1=df.loc[df['id_main_product'] == 1.0]
id1['rating'].mean()
```

But this way it would be really tedious work as I would have to do the same for each ID, as the ID´s rank from 1 to 100. How can I do it for all the ID´s but just with one code?

Comment: `df.groupby('id_main_product')['rating'].mean()` ?